# Auto populate input fields based on jsonp response

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui

I'm trying to figure out how I can get two input fields populated based on the response I get from a jsonp request.

I get all the info I want from the jsonp request, but I cant figure out how to get that into the input fields.

If some of you would be so kind to help me out, you can find the code at http://jsfiddle.net/prodac/sLr7N/

Thanks a bunch!

-Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add in the `select` function something like :

```
$("#state").val(ui.item.state);
```

Here is the completed fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sLr7N/5/

Answer (score 1):

in the

```
select: function( event, ui ){}
```

you have assign the value to the input using their id, like this:

```
 select: function( event, ui ) {
                $('#state').val(ui.item.state); 
                $('#country').val(ui.item.country);
}
```